# Auto-resized navigationBar title misplaced

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have a UINavigationBar with a title of variable length. To make sure the title fits without being truncated I've implemented the following code in my **`viewDidLoad()`:**

```
let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40))
titleLabel.text = "\(petsName)'s Day"
titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
self.navBar.topItem?.titleView = titleLabel
```

However, because I have a bar button item, the title is being moved over to the left:

[image: navbar]

Is there any way to implement the code above but keep the text center aligned within the navigation bar?

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Change width to device width and titleLabel align it to center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.. may be worked

```
var view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 40))
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 40))
label.text = "Joys Day"
label.textAlignment = .center
 label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
view.addSubview(label)
navigationItem?.titleView = view
```

Comment: Do you know why this solution is lowering my title text compared to my other views that have the same font size? See here: http://imgur.com/a/LnQzp

Comment: Sorry set your font to label...label font not set in this code.. is problem then increase height

Comment: I am. Here is my full code with your solution: https://gist.github.com/MarksCode/ea14a0a984fd8384399893c2d987ebb8

Comment: But I still can't figure out why the text is lower than normal

Comment: try to increase font & height...issue in this.

Answer (score 1):

Change `titleLabel` width to device width and align it to center. Try this:

```
    let deviceWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: deviceWidth, height: 40))
    titleLabel.text = "My Test Title"
    titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: This does not center the label in the nav bar as requested in the question.